# Feature Request: Managed Metadata Graph API to bring back 'Path Of Term'

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, taxonomy

I have been using the new Graph APIs to return [Managed Metadata Terms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/termstore-term-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http).

One thing that is missing that I require is the path of the term. It can be returned in the JSOM and CSOM. The client I'm working for has large termsets, and without displaying the path of the term to the user, it makes it difficult for them to select the one they want.

Also, the [TaxonomyPicker](https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/TaxonomyPicker/) currently returns JSON, but when you pick a term it returns an `IPickerTerm` that contains:

- Key: The ID of the term
- Name: The name of the term
- Path: The path of the term
- TermSet: The Id of the parent TermSet of the term
- TermSetName: The Name of the parent TermSet of the term

I mainly want the Path of the term, but if the other values can be returned as well that would be great. If the API can return this information this SPFX can also be updated so that it uses the REST API instead of JSOM.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Can you please file your feature request at https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/ so that Microsoft can consider it.

Comment: User voice found here https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/41706994-include-the-path-to-the-term-in-the-managed-metada